# Manipulating forms with JavaScript or jQuery generated by dynamics.com not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom

Some of the forms are created and generated by dynamics.com. I try to overrule the styling by manipulating the DOM. Locally it's working, but on the server somehow the JavaScript is not working.

My js file is positioned just before the closing `<body>` tag.

In the DOM the HTML is rendered like below:

```
<div data-editorblocktype="Field-checkboxList" style="">
  <div class="lp-form-field" data-required-field="false">
    <label class="lp-ellipsis" for="29239e83-42a6-ea11-a812-000d3ad7c1cb" title="">The title</label>
      <input class="lp-form-fieldInput" type="checkbox" value="125810000">
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("div[data-editorblocktype=Field-checkboxList] .lp-ellipsis").classList.add('bg-red');
}
```

But than I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

With jQuery I tried the following:

```
if (window.jQuery) {
     $('div[data-editorblocktype=Field-checkboxList] .lp-ellipsis').addClass('text-orange-500', window.parent.document);
```

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: If it is returning null, then either your selector is wrong, or the elements do not exist yet.

Comment: But really, there should be an easier way to do this.  Defining your own `<style>` with those rules, after any styling by the original source, should override those previously defined rules.  You shouldn't have to do this with javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @Heretic Monkey that makes sense. So in my case what would be the best option? I can't move my script easily because I build all with webpack etc?

Comment: @Taplar I started overriding the CSS but there where so much classes and styling that manipulating the existing ones is easier in this case I think.

Comment: I don't see any options listed, and you don't mention the use of webpack in your question. All my comment was saying is that you need to check when your code is loaded and what your selector is selecting (if indeed anything is matched). Since you've not shared the HTML structure or where the code is loaded, we can't help with either question. You'll need to do some work to figure it out, or give more information into the specifics.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I update my question with some HTML.

Comment: When you override css, you do not have to do a complete replacement.  You can change just the options you want.

Comment: @Taplar but I use Tailwind, so it's more consistent (and handy) to replace the classes. That should be possible isn't it? But somehow it's still blocked. Nothing is changing. I don't know what to do?